# Function that returns a tuple gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

What does this error mean? I'm trying to make a function that returns a tuple. I'm sure i'm doing all wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
from random import randint
A = randint(1,3)
B = randint(1,3)
def make_them_different(a,b):
    while a == b:
        a = randint(1,3)
        b = randint(1,3)
        return (a,b)
new_A, new_B = make_them_different(A,B)
```

Comment: If it worked, this would be a very funny way to choose two different integers from a range. And it would scale horribly, for example if you had to choose 20 integers out of `range(1,30)`. Better use `random.sample(range(1,4), 2)`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code returns `None` if `a != b`.

Since, you have the `return` statement inside the while loop, if the while loop never gets executed, Python returns the default value of `None` which cannot be assigned to `new_A, new_B`.

```
>>> print make_them_different(2, 3)
None

>>> print make_them_different(2, 2)
(2, 1)
```

You could fix this by returning the default values (since they are different and that's what you intend to do)

```
def make_them_different(a,b):
    while a == b:
        a = randint(1,3)
        b = randint(1,3)
    return (a,b)  # Dedented the return line.
```

Demo -

```
>>> make_them_different(2, 2)
(3, 2)
>>> make_them_different(2, 3)
(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent the return one level lower:

```
from random import randint
A = randint(1,3)
B = randint(1,3)
def make_them_different(a,b):
    while a == b:
        a = randint(1,3)
        b = randint(1,3)
    return (a,b)
new_A, new_B = make_them_different(A,B)
```

Otherwise a,b will be regenerated only once - they may collide again after that, since you're never looping.